# Mailchimp, PayPal / Stripe Integration for Newsletter

Tags: paypal

I have been looking everywhere and cant seem to find what I am looking for. All I can find is the tutorial on how to add the IPN to paypal for mailchimp.

I have a mailing list I would like to charge subscribers for monthly. I would like to give them the option of being able to use a credit card and paypal. Does mailchimp support this or any email mailing list providers that you guys know of I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp alone won't support that.  You'll need to setup a subscription sign-up on your site using PayPal Standard or Express Checkout.

Then you could setup your PayPal IPN to automatically add email addresses from PayPal transactions into your MailChimp newsletter, but again, MailChimp isn't going to handle subscription setup for you.

Comment: Ok so I'll need a membership plugin then for Wordpress?

Comment: Depends on exactly what your goals are.  You could just make a standard PayPal subscription button and drop it into any page/post in WordPress.  You might want to take a look at [PayPal WP Button Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-wp-button-manager/) for that.

Comment: All i need is for them to pay monthly and when they sign up I capture their email addresses in my list

Comment: Then yeah, you could use the PayPal WP Button Manager plugin to easily create subscription buttons and drop them into your pages/posts.  Then you could use PayPal IPN for WordPress to automatically add email addresses to your list.

Comment: I actually figured one part out, I created a pay pal button, they pay, and use the return URL to go to a different URL on my side for them to subscribe to that specific mailing list....Only issue now, and where i am lost in is how to hide that return URL so people arent able to share it...Also trying to think of a way that they can cancel the subscrition withou me having to make a login/log out deal for them

Comment: That is not the recommended way to handle it.  There is no guarantee that a user will make it back to your site even with Auto-Return enabled in PayPal.  They could simply close the browser before they're sent back, and then they would never see that page.  IPN will trigger regardless, so it is the recommended way to handle post-transaction actions.

Comment: Is that with paypal data transfer? Do you have a tutorial i can look over, i am completely lost here man

Comment: Step 1 would be to install and configure [PayPal IPN for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/).  Then you would need to write a very simple hook function that adds the email address to your list when new transactions occur.  If you'd rather save some time you could [submit a quote request](https://www.angelleye.com/quote-request/) and I could give you a bid on doing it for you.